# How to use jQuery .index() to return different results depending which <a> has been clicked

Tags: jquery

I have been looking for on this site and throughout google trying to sort this out with out any luck. Also I am new to jQuery so this may be elementary but here goes.... What I have is an unordered list with eight line elements, all links. When clicked each link should open a different article in a lightbox depending on which link has been clicked. The code I have written opens the article in the lightbox but will always open the first article of the first link to be clicked. Then if its closed and click a different link it opens the article for the first link. I am sure I need to use .index() to know what link has been clicked, but not sure how to go about it? Can anyone help me with this? Here is what part of my code looks like....

```
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#" id="a" class="links">Month One</a></li>
          <article>Here is a long article that opens in lightbox</article>

          <li><a href="#" id="b" class="links">Month Two</a></li>
          <article>Here is a long article that opens in lightbox</article>

    </ul>

    <script>
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
switch (e.target) {
    case "#a":
       $overlay.append($articelNameA);
      $articleNameA.show();
        break;
    case "#b":
     $overlay.append($articleNameB);
     $articleNameB.show();
        break;

}
```

});

```
//adds overlay to html body
$("body").append($overlay);

//capture click event on empty link
$("#a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var contentText = $('#aarticle').html();                   

  $articleNameA.html(contentText);   
  //opens the overlay on click
   $overlay.show();
});

$("#b").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var contentText = $('#barticle').html();                   

  $articleNameB.html(contentText);   
  //opens the overlay on click
   $overlay.show(); 
   }); 


//Exit overlay on click
$overlay.click(function(){
  $overlay.hide();
});
});
    </script>
```

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to find out index of it's closing li , this will give the index
your js:

```
 $('a').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).closest('li').index('ul > li'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/21tbykfw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

** I can give you two ways of solving this...**

A. using Event target ex:

```
     $('a').on('click',function(e){
    switch(e.target){
    case xvalue:
    //do this
    break;
    case yvalue:
    //do thatbrea;
    }
   /* and so on...*/
    });
```

B. passing a data source as the content... Ex:

```
 <script>
$('a').on('click',function(e){
var html = "<div>His name is:" + $(this).data("source") + "</div>"
$('body').append(html);// Appends the element to the body
});
</script>
```

You can check the second example here: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/084hq8m8/

Comment: After a bit of tweaking the event target method is giving me the same results as the original code. It opens the lightbox with the first article clicked for all links.

Answer (score 0):

Here I sorted out the problem not using .index but all the same its working. I think there has to be a more effecient method no?

```
<ul class="links">
      <li><a href="#" id="a">Month One</a></li>
      <article>Here is a long article that opens in lightbox</article>

      <li><a href="#" id="b">Month Two</a></li>
      <article>Here is a long article that opens in lightbox</article>

</ul>

<script>
     var linkA = $('#a');
     var linkB = $('#b');

    $('.links a').click(function(){ 
   if($(this).is("#a")){
      $overlay.append($linkA);
      $linkA.show();
   } else if($(this).is("#b")) {
     $overlay.append($linkB);
     $linkB.show();
   } 
});

$("body").append($overlay);

$('.links a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault; 

          if($(this).is("#a")){
          var contentTextA = $('#aarticle').html(); 

          $linkA.html(contentTextA);   
          //opens the overlay on click
           $overlay.show();

       } else if($(this).is("#b")) {
          var contentTextB = $('#barticle').html();                   
          $linkB.html(contentTextB);   
              //opens the overlay on click
               $overlay.show(); 
       } 
});

$overlay.click(function(){
    location.reload();
  });
});
</script>
```

Two problems I still have with the code are first..... I feel like there has to be a more effecient method than so many else if statements the real code has 8 links so its a ton of repeating. And second on the exit of the lightbox the only way I could get the link to reset and open a new article was to do location.reload, that way every time a lightbox is closed and a new link clicked the proper article is loaded into the lightbox, but that causes the link unordered list called links to go back to its hidden state and the user must reopen unordered list called links causing a bit of inconvenience to the user.